How are type class/trait/interface instances in functional languages represented in memory?
I'm curious to know about the low-level implementation details of how high-level functional languages/compilers implement type class instances under-the-hood. By type class, I mean the kind that a type can implement multiple different kinds of, even if some of them provide the same instance functions (e.g., a type could implement both class A and B, even if both of these provide a function foo).
What might the memory layout look like for the instance functions and how would it relate to how the type instantiating the type class is represented in memory? Diagrams like this one would be helpful:

What resources could I look into to learn more about the topic?
I'm hoping that learning about this will give me some ideas about how to implement similar concepts (ad-hoc polymorphism) in other, lower-level languages that don't have type classes.

e.g. googling "ghc typeclass implementation" gives you https://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/typeclass.html
